# How to disable/remove the option of "phone number" from PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

PayPal Express Checkout is forcing my customers for their phone numbers even though it's presented as optional in the docs. I live in the UK but my target customers live in the United States. Are US customers fine with entering their phone numbers in the PayPal Checkout Page? If not how do I disable it?

BTW my website is hosted on Shopify if it helps.

I have already turned off phone number required in "Website Preferences" in PayPal.